# Attempting SQLi against website with WAF filter

Tags: webserver, sql-injection, databases, sql-server, waf

I was pentesting a website when I discovered that the URL included the `id` parameter. Because of this, I knew that the `id` parameter might be vulnerable to SQLi. I received a `200` response and found no sign that the injection was successful after I sent the following request to the server:

`Example.com/php?id=-15 /*!u%6eion*/ /*!se%6cect*/ 1,2,3,`

After fighting with this website and WAF for about an hour, I noticed the website was continuing to respond with a `200` to every single request. I also tried running `sqlmap`, but the WAF blocked my connection.

So how can I know if this website is vulnerable to SQLi or not?

Can anyone please help me understand why my injection attempt was unsuccessful?

Comment: Your question is a bit controversial, at first you say: _"So i knew "id" param is vulnerable to Sql injection"_ and then you ask _"So how to know this website is vulnerable to sql injection or not?"_. Not every website that uses `id` as a parameter name is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: I had read many blog posts about Sql injection. And "id" param is Vulenerble to Idor and sqli. I ask this question cause i am bit confused cause when I request any statement to the server it gives every response 200 Ok I am not sure about  WAF blocking my payloads or not. If WAF block then the response would be 400 ,404 ,500

Comment: But there is a Waf that had been detected by Sqlmap. Then why would WAF show 200 ok to every single requests

Comment: Just because it returns a 200 response does not mean there is sqli

Comment: My point is that the name of the parameter is **not** an indication that a website is vulnerable to sql-injection. Many websites use `id` as a parameter name and are not vulnerable. Also there might be many reasons why for every request you get a 200 status code.

Comment: Just to remark @game0ver comment. Having a url parameter a specific name does not mean anything. You can have and URL like `page.php?id=15&otherParameter=44` but the application could handle right the `id` parameter but handle wrong, and thus being vulnerable to SQLi, the `otherParameter`. Naming parameters means nothing about the behaviour of the underlying code.

Comment: Your question seems to have a lot of assumptions. I would go through the process of validating those assumptions first. Your SQLi injection attempt may have failed *because it is not vulnerable to SQLi!* So, your entire question boils down to "how do you know if a site is vulnerable to SQLi?" And that question is very broad, and there are multiple tests that you could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is a false assumption

> I discovered that the URL included the id parameter. Because of this, I knew that the id parameter might be vulnerable to SQLi.

Naming parameters means nothing about the behaviour of the underlying code.

For example, you could have and URL like `page.php?id=15&otherParameter=44` but the application could handle right the `id` parameter and handle wrong, and thus being vulnerable to SQLi, `otherParameter` parameter.

So far, from the info provided, there is no way to tell if there is a posible SQLi (the WAF could be configured to return `200` responses for blocked requests to avoid leaking information), there is just a false asumption that it is vulnerable.

Comment: I'm also curious if the existence of the WAF is an assumption.